# ajax call to controller method after formsubmit and getdata

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

i have One Method POST Startmailing() in  controller 
When I submit form on Button Click  Startmailing()method start execution And Count in that method increases.

```
 public void Startmailing()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            { 
                _count++;

            } 

        }
```

What I want to do is After Form Submit I want to call Another Method **GetCount()** of that controller which returns Count

```
 [HttpPost] 
        public ActionResult GetCount() 
        {
            return Json(new { Data = _count });
        }
```

But i Am facing Problem It Only Executes **Getcount()** method again and again And only returns 0.. How can I Execute Both Method And get Increased Count

i tried to call this method after `formsubmit()`
       Send

```
  function submitform() {

 var f = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];

    f.submit();
    showCount();
    function showCount() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetCount", "Test")',
            type: "POST",
            success: function (a) {
                alert(a.Data);
            }
        });
        setTimeout(showCount(), 1000);
    }
```

Thanks In Advance !

Any help Will be Appreciated..
 Edit Questions if Required..

Comment: You have specify setTimeout(showCount(), 1000); because of that it fires in interval again and again

Comment: Yes I want Call That After every one second then only i will get increased count  But Also want  Startmailing() method to be execute otherwise i will get only 0.. first understand my questions

Comment: can you please post code of submit form i.e button click

Comment: `_count` is a static field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While posting data settimer which get count from GetCount method after every 5s...I used thread.sleep just to hold for moment... In your case this is not required as mail sending itself takes time...

In controller

```
    public static long Count;

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetCount()
    {
        return Json(Count);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void Index(FormCollection data)
    {
        Count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Count++;
        }
    }
```

Used this script

```
    <script>
    function btnSubmit() {
         window.setInterval(starttimer, 5000);

         var f = document.getElementsByTagName('form');
         f.submit();
    }

    function starttimer() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/SendMail/GetCount",
            dataType: 'json',
            asyn: false,
            timeout:5000,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#Count").val(data);
            }
        });
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you must call `Startmailing` first becouse _count has default value 0

```
    [HttpPost] 
    public ActionResult GetCount() 
    {
        Startmailing()
        return Json(new { Data = _count });
    }
```

Comment: on form submit startmailing will call first and then  getcount  @using (Html.BeginForm("Startmailing", "Test", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))

Comment: when you call GetCount, you create new controller obj with his default values and  _count =0 or value in constructor, so it will return 0

Comment: So What is The Solution??

Answer (score 0):

First **send form serialize data** in ajax call and on success call your function:

```
$.ajax({
url: '@Url.Action("Sta‌​rtmailing", "Test")',
dataType: 'json',
data: $("#form").serialize(),
type: 'POST',
success: function (result) {
    showCount();
},
error: function (xhr) {
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For me in `Startmailing()` you can save(after loop) count to Session:

```
 public void Startmailing()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        { 
            _count++;

        } 
      Session["Count"] = _count;
    }
```

And in method read this variable:

```
 [HttpPost] 
    public ActionResult GetCount() 
    {
        return Json(new { Data = Session["Count"]});
    }
```

Comment: f.submit();  showCount(); in this case once showcount method starts its execution startmail()  method is not executing

Comment: Try change Startmailing() and add: Session["Count"] = _count++ to inside your loop